# How to change polymer built output path?

Tags: polymer

`polymer build` command output the result to the build directory.

Is there any way to change the output path?

```
/* Output directory example */

./build/  
├── es5-bundled  
├── es6-bundled  
├── es6-unbundled  
└── polymer.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the names of the subfolders within build folder to any name you like. Just change the name property in builds array of your polymer.json file.
See the [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/tools/polymer-json#builds) for this.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, no method exists to change the build output path (see [this issue](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/684)). You can, however, use [`polymer-build`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/polymer-build) (the same package used by `polymer-cli`) with `gulp`, which gives you a lot more control over those kind of things.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.